# How do I get the Organization name from an X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I can get the full subject string from an `X509Certificate2` via the `Subject` property, but is there any way to get a specific value from the subject string (e.g. just `O = "Stack Exchange, Inc."`)?  The `SubjectName` property looked promising, but it seems to only contain more ways of dumping the entire subject into a string.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Portable.BouncyCastle](https://github.com/onovotny/bc-csharp) library (available [via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/)) there is an [X509Name](https://github.com/onovotny/bc-csharp/blob/netstandard/crypto/src/asn1/x509/X509Name.cs) class that allows you to do something like this:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...

X509Certificate2 certificate = ...

var name = new X509Name(certificate.Subject);
var organization = name
  .GetValueList(X509Name.O)
  .OfType<string>()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, the [`X509Certificate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have any property besides `Subject` to get the information that you need.

But if you really need to have the *Organization* name separeted, 
you could have it with a simple [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) match:

```
var organization = Regex.Match(certificate.Subject, @"O\s?=(.*)\s").Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Correct regex patter is "O\s?=(.*?),\s"